# Параметры в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^qwe/(.*?)/?$ /system/modules/qwe/index.php?param=$1 [L]
```

Проблема в том, что **site.ru/qwe/ololo/?q=1** не поддерживается, а именно **параметр ?q=1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Флаг надо добавить:

```
RewriteRule ^qwe/(.*?)/?$ /system/modules/qwe/index.php?param=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо!